# using less-loader in webpack

Tags: webpack, less, less-loader

I am creating a bundle.js file with webpack. I have decided I want to start using LESS as well and I have tried to add the less-loader as per the instructions:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader

I ran:
    npm-install  less-loader --save-dev

Then I updated the webpack.config.js to include the rules:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    module: {
    //******** BELOW IS THE RULES U ADDED *************/
        rules: [{
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [{
              loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
              loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
              loader: 'less-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
            }]
        }],
         //******** ABOVE IS THE RULES U ADDED *************/
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ],
        rules: [
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              use: [
                { loader: "style-loader" },
                { loader: "css-loader" }
              ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'html-loader',
                  options: {
                    attrs: [':data-src']                  
                  }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Then I added a less file and required it like so:
    require("./Bootstrap/bootstrap-iso.less");

the less file is just a wrapper for bootstrap (I have also tried simplier css)

```
#entry {
    @import (less) './css/bootstrap.css';
  }
```

But I continue to get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/Bootstrap/bootstrap-iso.less
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| #entry {
|     @import (less) './css/bootstrap.css';
|   }
 @ ./src/entry.js 13:0-41
```

it seems that the loader is not loaded properly?

Answer (score 7):

It was my mistakes, I should not have had multiple rules properties.. see working webpack.config.js snippet:

```js
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(less)$/,
        use: [{
            loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
        }, {
            loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
        }, {
            loader: 'less-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
        }]
    },
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            { loader: "style-loader" },
            { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
                attrs: [':data-src']
            }
        }
    }
    ]
}
```